# Terminal stuck on "<waiting for any device>" after /fastboot oem unlock command

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung

I have been trying to unlock my phone's (Samsung Galaxy J5) bootloader with almost no success. I used adb for the process but it always gets stuck at `waiting for device`, after fastboot command `./fastboot oem unlock`

Idk why this is driving me crazy. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Is the phone in bootloader mode when you run the command? If you run `fastboot devices` with the phone in bootloader mode, is the device listed?